# Overflow causing entire page to scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

I am trying to create a page that doesn't scroll. Certain child elements on the page can scroll, but I'm trying to prevent the page as a whole from scrolling. I have a very nested child element that, when overflowed, receives a scroll bar, but also causes the main document to grow and receive a scroll bar as well.

This is the heart of the issue, but there are a few more nested levels that may be a factor.

```
<div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">    
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-red" style="height: 7%">
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-red" style="height: 3%">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green" style="max-height: 75%; height: 75%; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div class="bg-gray m-4" style="height: 2000px;">
                    The height of this content causes BOTH scroll bars to appear. I only want a bar on the 
                    'green section'
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red flex-grow-1">
    </div>            
</div>
```

This code pen demonstrates how my app is set up. The overflowing element is nested deep within many flex displays (coming from bootstrap 4 utility classes).

https://codepen.io/averyferrante/pen/YMdNpO

I want only the green section from the code pen to scroll, not the entire document to grow/scroll as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a couple of your containers are missing height definitions. As a result, the children of those containers ignore the percentage heights applied to them.

**Add this to your code:**

```
 <div class="flex-grow-1" style="height: calc(100% - 48px);">
```

This height rule gives the container a defined height while compensating for the height of its sibling.

**Another height rule was missing three levels down:**

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100" style="height: 100%;">
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyZWpG?editors=1100)

*More detailed explanations:*

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the detailed explanations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try playing with `position: absolute`? You can then set width and height as needed and the red box will see its scrollbar disappear!